# FB.getLoginStatus returns connected in every situation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I am building an iphone app with phonegap, and using the facebook javascript sdk.

```
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    if(response.status === 'connected'){
      alert("connected");
      var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
      var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    } 
    else if(response.status === 'not_authorized'){
      login();
    }
    else{
      login();
    }
   });
```

This function checks the status. But it alerts "connected" even i am not logged in to facebook with the xcode iphone simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you are logged on, maybe on browser or FB app. In my case, when I tested on smartphone, FB.getLoginStatus method always alerted 'connected' because I was logged on FB app.

Comment: i am testing it on the xcode simulator, and i am not logged in to any facebook account in the simulator.